# Pepper plant leaves turn brown with white spots

Tags: pests, peppers

I live in the pacific north west, I have some pepper plants that got infected with a weird disease that I can pin point. White spots that are in clusters sometimes and the leaves just turn yellow and brown.

[image: Pepper leaves with yellow discolouration]

Comment: is there anything that moves on the underside of the leaf?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at image number four at [this](https://plantvillage.psu.edu/posts/3546-chilli-pepper-white-powder-on-chilli-plants) site. I think this clearly resembles your photo. The conclusion is [whiteflies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitefly)

From wiki:

> The eggs of Aleyrodidae generally are laid near each other on the food
> plant, usually on a leaf, in spiral patterns or arcs, sometimes in
> parallel arcs.

[This source](https://whyfarmit.com/pepper-plant-problems/) suggests a cure:

> Whiteflies are resistant to chemical insecticides. Instead, use a
> homemade remedy of 1 tablespoon liquid soap, two parts rubbing alcohol
> and five parts water.
>
> Spray this solution onto the plant’s leaves to kill and prevent
> whiteflies.

**If you have healthy plants too, then quickly remove/destroy the damaged ones and save the treatment for later minor attacks on those you kept.**